# Looking for a way to wrap listed database results in a div

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create a window that will become a small popup window, containing a list of items coming from a database. Each of the items will be a checkbox. My problem is the list overflows down the div where I'd like it to instead shift a column over so that there's a few columns if there's a lot of records retrieved (there will be). I'm unsure exactly how to do that with the php/mysql retrieval-- I know I'd have to maybe have a new nieghboring div for every so many items-- does anyone know a good way of doing this? Here's the page source:

functions.php:

```
// returns an array of all active users
function getActiveUsers() {
    $con = mysql_connect("-","-","-");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    else {
        // connected to database successfully
    }
    mysql_select_db("casemanagers", $con);
    $result = mysql_query('select * from users where active=1 order by Name ASC');
    while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $arr[] = $row['Name'];
    }
    return $arr;
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="English (American)" lang="English (American)">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #userMenu {
            border-style:solid;
            border-size:1px;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            padding:20px;
            overflow:auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="userMenu" style="">
        <?php
            include_once('functions.php');
            $list = getActiveUsers();
            foreach ($list as $x){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your checkboxes in a list and float the list items

```
<div id="userMenu" style="">
<ul>
    <?php
        include_once('functions.php');
        $list = getActiveUsers();
        foreach ($list as $x){
            echo '<li><input type="checkbox" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'</li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#userMenu li { width: 33%; float:left } // will produce 3 rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to float your divs left so it will list them left to right instead of just a column.

```
 <div id="userMenu" style="">
        <?php
            include_once('functions.php');
            $list = getActiveUsers();
            foreach ($list as $x){
                echo '<div class="item">';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#userMenu div.item{
float:left; margin:10px;
}
```